# PHP Armazenar Imagem em variável

Tags: php, html, image

É possível armazenar uma imagem em uma variável PHP (pega-lá por método "POST") e depois utiliza-lá para chamar a imagem em outros lugares? Assim como é feito com Strings vindas de input do HTML.

Comment: O que é esta imagem? Um arquivo enviado através do *input* `file`? Pode salvar a imagem em disco no servidor e armazenar apenas o caminho desta na variável? E que "outros lugares" seriam estes?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acho que ele quer gravar no banco, e depois solicitar com uma URL mesmo

Comment: Na verdade era guardar em uma variável mesmo, o arquivo vem de um input do tipo file em um formulário, todas as informações vem do formulário para o PHP e ai gero um PDF, queria saber se dava para fazer isso com a imagem que vem do upload para que ela apareça no PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `input type="hidden"` guarde o caminho da imagem no value, assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="img" value="caminho_da_imagem" />
```

E se quiser usar futuramente no site, pode guarda-la numa variavel `$_SESSION` e usá-la assim:

```
<img src="<?=$_SESSION['img']; ?>" />
```

Espero que seja isto que pretende.